# Fatal: No program entry point

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I'm using TASM for a class assignment. I'm getting a "Fatal: no program entry point" error when attempting to use Turbo Link Version 7.1.30.1 to create the .EXE file. The program assembles properly.

I've attempted to use startpoint: and start: before. Nothing thus far has worked.

```
    TITLE NOSICHA1.ASM

        .MODEL  SMALL
        .STACK  100h

        .DATA

        INCLUDE CONST.INC
        INCLUDE GETINT.ASM
        INCLUDE PUTINT.ASM

    X       DW  ?
    Y       DW  ?
    Z       DW  ?
    OUTMSG1     DB  'Z(x, y) = 27 * x - 14 * y + (10 * x + 17 * y) * (19 * x - 3 * y)'
        INMSG1      DB  CR, LF, 'PLEASE ENTER THE VALUE OF x: $'
        INMSG2      DB  CR, LF, 'PLEASE ENTER THE VALUE OF y: $'
        OUTMSG2     DB  CR, LF, 'THE VALUE OF Z IS: $'

    .CODE

        EXTRN   GETINT: PROC, PUTINT: PROC

MAIN    PROC

    MOV     AX, @DATA
        MOV     DS, AX

        MOV     AH, WRSTR
        MOV     DX, OFFSET OUTMSG1
        INT     DOSFUNC

        MOV     AH, WRSTR
        MOV     DX, OFFSET INMSG1
        INT     DOSFUNC

        CALL    GETINT
        MOV     Y, AX

        MOV     AH, WRSTR
        MOV     DX, OFFSET INMSG2

        CALL    GETINT
        MOV     Y, AX

        MOV     AX, 10
        IMUL    Y
        MOV     BX, AX
        MOV     AX, 17
        IMUL    Y
        ADD AX, BX
        MOV CX, AX

        MOV AX, 19
        IMUL    Y
        MOV BX, AX
        MOV AX, 3
        IMUL    Y
        SUB BX, AX
        MOV AX, BX

        IMUL    CX
        MOV CX, AX

        MOV AX, 27
        IMUL    X
        ADD CX, BX

        MOV AX, 14
        IMUL    Y
        SUB CX, AX

        MOV Z, CX

        MOV AH, WRSTR
        MOV DX, OFFSET OUTMSG2
        INT DOSFUNC

    MOV AX, CX
    CALL    PUTINT

        MOV AH, RET2DOS
        INT DOSFUNC

MAIN    ENDP

    END     MAIN
```

Comment: `END     MAIN` as the last line of the file is what sets the entry point, I think.  But I haven't used TASM or DOS tools.  Have you tried not indenting it relative to `main endp`?  The code you posted in the question has some pretty random indenting, unless you used code-formatting on parts of it (indent by 4) before my edit.

Comment: You might also try adding a blank line at the end of the file.  I've seen that help.

Comment: I'd be concerned with `INCLUDE GETINT.ASM` and `INCLUDE PUTINT.ASM` .Usually you don't include ASM files but you generate object files out of them and then link them together. It is possible something in those files causes problems. I'd have to see all the files you are using to make an assessment.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Agreed. I’m going to predict that both have their own `END`

Comment: @JohnBurger : That was my thinking as well.